# Ruby readline fails if process started with arguments

Tags: ruby

I'm having the strangest issue. This code below works fine:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
h = Net::HTTP.new("localhost", 4567) 
while(l = gets.chomp!)
   res = h.post("/api/v1/service/general",l)
   puts res.body
end
```

However, with the small modification of getting host/port from parameters:

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
h = Net::HTTP.new(ARGV[0], ARGV[1]) 
while(l = gets.chomp!)
   res = h.post("/api/v1/service/general",l)
   puts res.body
end
```

..and starting with `ruby service.rb localhost 4567` ...

I get this error:

```
service.rb:4:in `gets': No such file or directory - localhost (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Using ruby 1.9.2p0 on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried `while (l = $stdin.gets.chomp!)`? Otherwise `Kernel#gets` reads from `ARGV`.

Comment: Really? That's interesting to learn. I love Ruby to pieces, but this is the principle of *most* surprise, IMHO. I would have to investigate this in-depth tomorrow! Sometimes I feel Ruby is making me un-learn too much!

Comment: Ah, that worked. Is this normal behaviour? I can't remember having this problem before, and I've written quite some scripting in Ruby before - although on earlier versions. Why would you ever want `gets` or `readline` to work with the first argument?

Comment: Yes, this is standard behavior. From the `Kernel#gets` docs: "Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the command line." With the explicit receiver, you call `IO.gets` which "Reads the next ``line’’ from the I/O stream".

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
h = Net::HTTP.new(ARGV.shift, ARGV.shift) 
while(l = gets.chomp!)
```

It will still fail if you pass in more than two arguments. You should call `ARGV.clear` after constructing `h` if you want to deal with that.

Comment: You also can give `gets` an explicit receiver (`$stdin`), then it works without clearing `ARGV`. See my answer.

Comment: Yup this worked as well. I tried setting `ARGV[0]` to `nil`, but that didn't work. I guess there's a special case `if ARGV.length>0` or something