# rspec issue believed to be with gets.chomp call

Tags: ruby, input, rspec, gets

I am having trouble or am confused with an rspec error when running:

```
rspec -fd game_spec
```

[image: respec error messaage]

(the above is only the beginning of a long eror message)

When I run it without the -fd, it works... but it looks goofy... something is wrong.  I start getting error messages when I use gets.chomp but I've looked at similar examples that use it.  Does 'the_word' have to be set in initialize?  Does gets.chomp or can it?  I appreciate any help.  Below is game file and its rspec so far.  I do not want to change much at all.  I just want to get what I have so far working and keep pushing on.  Thanks!

[image: user interface with issue]
[image: rspec file]

Comment: by the way, it's preferrable to add a code block to the question than to use a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `gets` reads from `ARGV` (argument variables), such as the `-fd` flag you're giving to `rpsec`.

You can recreate this situation pretty easily:

```
> ruby -e "puts gets.chomp" ASD
-e:1:in `gets': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ASD (Errno::ENOENT)
    from -e:1:in `gets'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

You can prevent this from happening by clearing out `ARGV` before calling `gets.`

```
> ruby -e "ARGV.clear; puts gets.chomp" ASD
asd # <-- I then type this
asd # <-- and this is printed
```

You can't just say `ARGV = []` because it's a constant, but calling `clear` is fine  because it's not redefining the variable.

In short, just put this somewhere before `gets.chomp`:

```
ARGV.clear
```

Here's another question on the topic: [Ruby readline fails if process started with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965885/ruby-readline-fails-if-process-started-with-arguments)

Comment: thanks a bunch.  so where exactly do you place it before it?  like this? 'code' puts "Please STRATEGICALLY provide me with a word, player one."
game.the_word = ARGV.clear gets.chomp.split('')'code'

Comment: put it on its own line, before the `game.the_word` assignment and `gets.chomp` call. If you're not using `ARGV` in your code (and you don't seem to be), you can put it at the top of the file.

Comment: got it!  awesome.  much appreciated  ARGV.clear; gets.chomp.split('')

Answer (score 0):

I used `$stdin.gets.chomp`, so the code will be:

```
game.the_word = $stdin.gets.chomp
```

According to my research, `gets.chomp` will first check for content in the ARGV and if it doesn't find any it uses the standard input. Doing it that way will read the user input directly.